# Neo4j and Cypher: Getting counts from connected nodes that share relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Sorry about the title. Trying to figure out the best way to word my issue.

I am working on a project that has 3 nodes (dealerships, cars, and colors (of the car). I want to use my graph database instead of a MySQL database.

I have a dealership that is connected to a year/make/model of a car and each dealer offers that ymm car in certain colors. So it appears that the connection is something like (d:Dealership)-[:OFFERS]->(c:Car)-[:PAINTED]->(co:Color). But some dealerships offer the same ymm of car in different colors. So what I need to figure out is the correct relationship and cypher to connect from dealer to car to color to be able to COLLECT() the colors of each car for each dealership.

Where I am drawing a blank is since multiple dealers might be connected to the same car node (since it general) and then off to colors, how to get all the cars that a dealership offers and all the colors of that car that THEY offer. Even if the car is connected to 10 colors (total possible), a dealership might be only offer 5.

Does every car need to be a unique node to accomplish this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `Offer` node to represent a specific offering from a dealer. For example:

```
(d:Dealership)-[:OFFERS]->(o:Offer),
(c:Car)<-[:MODEL]-(o)-[:PAINTED]->(co:Color)
```

The `Offer` node could also contain the data specific to that offering, like `price`.